# Scrape multiple pages with json

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape multiple pages with json but they will provide me error

```
    import requests
    import json
    import pandas as pd
    headers = {
        'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Origin': 'https://www.nationalhardwareshow.com',
        'Referer': 'https://www.nationalhardwareshow.com/',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    }
    
    params = {
        'x-algolia-agent': 'Algolia for vanilla JavaScript 3.27.1',
        'x-algolia-application-id': 'XD0U5M6Y4R',
        'x-algolia-api-key': 'd5cd7d4ec26134ff4a34d736a7f9ad47',
    }
    for i in range(0,4):
        data = '{"params":"query=&page={i}&facetFilters=&optionalFilters=%5B%5D"}'
    
        resp = requests.post('https://xd0u5m6y4r-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/event-edition-eve-e6b1ae25-5b9f-457b-83b3-335667332366_en-us/query', params=params, headers=headers, data=data).json()
    
        req_json=resp
        df = pd.DataFrame(req_json['hits'])
        f = pd.DataFrame(df[['name','representedBrands','description']])
        print(f)
```

the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e:\ScriptScraping\Extract data from json\uk.py", line 31, in <module>
df = pd.DataFrame(req_json['hits']) KeyError: 'hits'
```

Comment: can you  provide us the error ?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\ScriptScraping\Extract data from json\uk.py", line 31, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(req_json['hits'])
KeyError: 'hits'`

Comment: I meant in the question ...

Comment: in question show error in these lin `df = pd.DataFrame(req_json['hits'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to concatenate the variable i with data parameter

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
headers = {
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Origin': 'https://www.nationalhardwareshow.com',
    'Referer': 'https://www.nationalhardwareshow.com/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"'
    }
    
params = {
    'x-algolia-agent': 'Algolia for vanilla JavaScript 3.27.1',
    'x-algolia-application-id': 'XD0U5M6Y4R',
    'x-algolia-api-key': 'd5cd7d4ec26134ff4a34d736a7f9ad47'
    }
lst=[]
for i in range(0,4):
    data = '{"params":"query=&page='+str(i)+'&facetFilters=&optionalFilters=%5B%5D"}'
    
    resp = requests.post('https://xd0u5m6y4r-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/event-edition-eve-e6b1ae25-5b9f-457b-83b3-335667332366_en-us/query', params=params, headers=headers, data=data).json()
    
    req_json=resp
    df = pd.DataFrame(req_json['hits'])
    f = pd.DataFrame(df[['name','representedBrands','description']])
    lst.append(f)
    #print(f)
d=pd.concat(lst)
print(d)
```

Comment: when make csv file data is overwrite

Comment: Thre are 4 dfs meaning each page contains a df. concat the dfs  into   single df

Comment: how we concatenate 4 df

Comment: I have make only one df how can I make 4 df?

Comment: @Amen Aziz I've edited

Answer (score 0):

It is returning status_code 400 as the request is bad. You are sending wrongly formatted data. Change:

`data = '{"params":"query=&page={i}&facetFilters=&optionalFilters=%5B%5D"}'`

To

`data = '{"params":"query=&page='+str(i)+'&facetFilters=&optionalFilters=%5B%5D"}'`

For it to work. Hope I could help.

Comment: when make csv file they overwrite data any solution for it?

Comment: What do you mean?